# Pandas: Group by with condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, transactions

I have to group the transactions (InvoiceNo) that do not contain any `SmallSeller` product (SellCategory) and I'm not sure on how to proceed.

I will finally have to compare the revenue (`Quantity*UnitPrice`) generated by both types of transactions (the ones containing a `SmallSeller` product vs the ones not containing any `SmallSeller` product).

(this is an example of my data)

```
    InvoiceNo   SellCategory    Revenue

      23        Medium-Seller     54
      23         Best-Seller     108
      23         Best-Seller      71
      24        Medium-Seller     43
      24         Small-Seller     18
      25         Best-Seller      89
      25         Small-Seller     23
      26        Medium-Seller     65
      26         Best-Seller      98
      26         Small-Seller     23
```

[Screenshot of my data's table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTuSw.png)

Comment: Please print the data here instead of giving a screenshot..

Comment: Welcome to SO! screenshots are not encouraged as we have to type the data. Can you please paste the data directly in the question and format as code?

Comment: Sorry! Really new here... I hope this is better!

Answer (score 0):

You can groupby the following way and then proceed to further operations :

```
df[df.SellCategory != 'Small-Seller'].groupby('InvoiceNo')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_pivot=df.pivot_table(index='InvoiceNo',columns='SellCategory',values='Revenue',aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
```

Comment: Code-only answers will not support the learning process of the question author which is part of the mission of SO. It would be appreciated if you would add an explanation to your code.

Comment: This answer is good, only thing is that we need to combine the columns 'Medium-Seller' and 'Best-Seller' in the end.

Comment: Thank you! Although I am having problems to sum, because of the "NaN". How to tell python to take NaN as 0?

Comment: I apologize for being new and not aware of the "answering" rules but to answer your question, just add a .fillna(0) like this df_pivot=df.pivot_table(index='InvoiceNo',columns='SellCategory',values='Revenue',aggfunc='sum').fillna(0).reset_index()

Comment: If you then want to combine the ‘Medium-Seller’ with the ‘Best-Seller’ columns, you can sum them up in another column like this
df_pivot['Medium_plus_best']=df_pivot['Medium-Seller']+df_pivot['Best-Seller']

Answer (score 0):

First we can pick relevant rows and then aggregate `Revenue` using groupby on `InvoiceNo`.
Finally, we concatenate the two kinds of dataframes in the end and rename the columns:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df[df['SellCategory'] == 'Small-Seller'].groupby('InvoiceNo').sum(), df[df['SellCategory'] == 'Small-Seller'].groupby('InvoiceNo').sum()], 1)

df1.columns = ['Revenue_Small_Seller', 'Revenue_without_Small_Seller']
```